# Probabilities with quadratic equations!

Tags: probability

[image]

Basically i have never seen probabilities linked with quadratic equations like these and so have no idea how to interpret this question, would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is less to the problem than meets the eye. There are only $4$ possible quadratic equations in this problem, $x^2+x+1=0$, $x^2+x-1=0$, $x^2-x+1=0$, and $x^2-x-1=0$. The second and the fourth have real solutions, and the other two do not. So the required probability is $\Pr((U,V)=(1,-1))+\Pr((U,V)=(-1,-1))$, or more simply $\Pr(V=-1)$.

For the conditional expectation, let $a=\Pr((U,V)=(1,-1)$ and let $b=\Pr((U,V)=(-1,-1)$. Let $r$ be the largest root of $x^2+x-1=0$, and let $s$ be the largest root of $x^2-x-1=0$. Then the conditional expectation you are looking for is $\frac{a}{a+b}r+\frac{b}{a+b}s$.

This is because the conditional probability that $(U,V)=(1,-1)$ given that $V=-1$ is $\frac{a}{a+b}$.